# Is concatenating with "+" more efficient than separating with "," when using print?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I just noticed that if I use `+` for concatenation in the `print()` function and run the code in the shell the text appears more quickly. Whereas, when using `,`, the text appears much slower as if with a "being typed" animation effect.

Is there a efficiency difference between these two?

Comment: One difference is that `,` adds a space in between the two things being concatenated, while `+` just connects them as they are.

Comment: I'd be curious to read about the same topic with the `print` statement in Python 2.

Comment: One uses `sep` to separate strings (default is a space) and prints each in turn. The other constructs a new string and then prints it in one go. It seems that the latter is about twice as fast as the other.

Comment: You can answer the question for yourself by timing the operation.

Comment: Obviously for `int`s or `float`s (rather than `str`ings) the operations behave completely differently

Comment: What exactly was your command when you noticed the time difference?

Comment: I tested this using the timeit method with python3.6.2 and for printing the statement `hi how are you` 100000 times, using a `,` ended up being about `.6` seconds faster than using a `+`

Comment: I've never done python, but I would imagine that beside copying the bytes to a new string, it would also have to marshal the separate parameters when the comma is used.  With concatenation, the result string would be created first, then a single parameter is passed.  Then again, a decent optimizer should eliminate the difference.

Comment: Printing small amounts of text either way should never be so slow that there's a "being typed animation effect". How much text are you printing  (or better yet, post some code that shows both situations for you!)? Also, what shell are you running your program in?

Comment: I wonder if line buffering has somehow been disabled so that each argument is printed and flushed to the console separately? That would explain a large difference between the two. I'm not sure how to test that though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

edit: Seems the question was not so much about the nature of the operations as their speed, which is not discussed in this answer!

The difference is that with `+` you use concatenation to create a larger string to pass to the `print` function, while with `,` you pass multiple strings to the `print` function. Note that these behaviours are not special for the `print` function: concatenation is just a method on strings, and comma is always used to separate function arguments.

For example, using concatenation:

```
print('hello' + ' ' + 'world')
```

This first concatenates the three strings to form `'hello world'`, and then prints that.

While using multiple arguments:

```
print('hello', 'world')
```

This passes two strings to the `print` function. As you can read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), the  `print` function takes one or multiple objects as arguments, and prints them separated by another argument, `sep`, which by default is a space. So this produces the same output as the previous example.

Note that any number of arguments can be passed to the `print` function, and that these arguments in themselves can be concatenated strings:

```
print('i' + ' ' + 'want', 'to', 'print', 'some', 'strings')
```

The nice part is that you can specify the `sep` argument to change the behaviour:

```
print('mary', 'peter', 'bob', sep=' and ')
```

Result: `mary and peter and bob`

Comment: Great answer. Using comma uses the variables as *args in the print statement and using + passes a concatenated string into it. I have never thought of it this way. Thank @Marein

Comment: @binu.py No, don't think of it in Python terms, `print` takes all it's arguments in an `args` tuple internally. In case of `+`, `args` just contains a single element.

Comment: I am confused why this was the accepted answer when the question clearly asked about efficiency differences between them.

Answer (score 26):

Though I wouldn't suspect a large discrepancy between these, they are obviously slightly different.

A `print` call that concatenates literal strings might be joined by CPython's peephole optimizer before being printed thereby resulting in faster execution, this is *probably* what you're seeing. Besides that, with small strings, the fact that only one argument is passed and, as a result, `sep` isn't used is also a small benefit.

With larger strings, the need to create a large temporary string to hold their concatenation negates all speed differences achieved. (The fact that `sep` isn't used and only one argument is passed is trumped due to the size and their concatenation)

Using `,` in a print call will pass each string as an argument and separate it using the default `sep`. While this obviously requires a bit more work, it is constant work that, again, disappears when large strings are involved.

So, with small strings that actually get caught by the optimizer, concatenation is a bit faster:

```
%timeit print("a" + "b", file=f)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 µs per loop

%timeit print("a", "b", sep='', file=f)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.48 µs per loop
```

Even when the optimizer can't join them:

```
a = "a"; b = "b"

%timeit print(a + b, file=f)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 2 µs per loop

%timeit print(a, b, sep='', file=f)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.45 µs per loop
```

when the string sizes increase, this small difference is eclipsed:

```
s1, s2 = "s" * 100000, "s"*100000
%timeit print(s1 + s2, file=f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 374 µs per loop
%timeit print(s1, s2, sep='', file=f)
1000 loops, best of 3: 373 µs per loop
```

Comment: You probably should time `print("a", "b", file=f, sep="")` to do a proper comparison.

Comment: @jamesdlin though correct, it really makes no difference. Either way, it's simple enough to add. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious difference is that `print(a, b)` will put a separator (by default - a single space) between values of `a` and `b`, while `print(a + b)` won't. Performance-wise I would expect the comma version to be faster, as the plus version requires building a new string.

**Update:** using following code:

```
import timeit

t1 = timeit.timeit('print("aa", "bb")')
t2 = timeit.timeit('print("aa" + " " + "bb")')

print(t1, t2)
```

I've got `9.997510432032868 11.018277243943885` ie. about 10% difference in favour of the comma; however using slightly longer strings:

```
t1 = timeit.timeit('print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")')
t2 = timeit.timeit('print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"+" "+"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb")')
```

tipped the balance: `18.56978454696946 18.07760854391381`. Then I redirected output to a file and obtained even more interesting results:
`0.730336288921535 0.39260527514852583` for shorter and `0.7751083469484001 0.5140565759502351` for longer strings. **Apparently, the results are more heavily influenced by scrolling speed of my terminal than by Python code.**

Comment: Think your expectation is wrong - the string + version is faster

Comment: @barny My tests (using Python 3.5.3) show otherwise.

Comment: @Błotosmętek A quick `timeit` with Python 3.5.2 here tends to agree with barny. But it's really a small diff (0.1s from 10,000,000 iterations, stdout not altered, just a dumb print), so let's say it's insignificant for most use cases...

Comment: `timeit.timeit('print("a", "b")', number=1000000) // 12.137287584002479` vs `timeit.timeit('print("a" + " " + "b")', number=1000000) // 12.043687215991667`

(was 1M, not 10M, sorry about that). Obviously, there's two concatenation to do, to mimic the same output.

Comment: For me, `print('1', '2')` is about 10-20 ns slower than `print('1' + ' ' + '2')`

Answer (score 3):

`print(a + b + c)`, evaluates an expression and passes a single argument to print. The second, `print(a, b, c)`, just passes three arguments to print. This is almost the same output purely by chance: that's how print works. The second is not doing any concatenation, and is simply outputting each value separated by a space (which is print's default behavior).

the plus in the expression is doing concatenation, but the comma is not doing concatenation.

Concatenation creates each string in memory, and then combines them together at their ends in a new string (so this may **not be very memory friendly**), and then prints them to your output at the same time

Answer (score 2):

`+` can be used with strings to concatenate 2 strings. However  in python 2.X `,` is used in print to print item inline but in python 3.X if you put a `,` between 2 items the compiler converts the two items to a tuple. When used inside a print `+` is used to concatenate and hence they are printed together. but using `,` prints them with a space as it is printing 2 items of a tuple.
eg,

```
In [1]: print('abcd'+'pqrs')
abcdpqrs

In [2]: print('abcd','pqrs')
abcd pqrs

In [3]: x=('abcd'+'pqrs')

In [4]: y=('abcd','pqrs')

In [5]: x
Out[5]: 'abcdpqrs'

In [6]: y
Out[6]: ('abcd', 'pqrs')

In [7]: type(y)
Out[7]: tuple

In [8]: type(x)
Out[8]: str
```

Comment: You've got it backwards -  `print('abcd','pqrs')` creates a tuple in Python **2**, but in Python **3** it is just a function call with two arguments, no tuple is involved.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `+` operator, at the end of the creation of the whole string, and only after that, it will be printed, with the `,` it would be created by parts and printed as well. And as a lot of users already said, there is another factor, the concat of " " (white space), it takes times too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at the bytecode for both using `dis`.

```
import dis

def f1():
    print('Hello ' + 'world!')


def f2():
    print('Hello', 'world!')


print(dis.dis(f1))

 62           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Hello world!')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
None


print(dis.dis(f2))
 66           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello')
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('world!')
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 POP_TOP
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
None
```

You can see that the `print` with the comma calls `LOAD_CONST` twice in this case (or as many times as there are variables\strings). This is an indication that **concatenation is faster** and will get progressively faster the more strings you concatenate vs comma-separate.

Comment: However I tested this with the timeit method, and using a `,` ended up being faster than `+` for 100000 operations

Comment: Your example is biased by the fact Python has optimized your two constant strings into a single 'Hello world!' string. Try with variables as function argument, you will have a `dis` result quite different. Still faster, but not for the same reason.

Comment: @MaximeLorant The only reason functions are used here is to pass them to `dis`. In a *real-world* scenario one would simply `print` without wrapping the `print` statements in a function so I am not at all convinced that passing arguments to `f` would get us closer to the truth

Comment: @Ev.Kounis My point was a real use of `print` would be with two variables and not with two constant strings, optimized by your interpreter in your example. Try with global variables, you'll see there is the same amount of `LOAD_GLOBAL` in both cases. 

The difference will be the BINARY_ADD before the CALL_FUNCTION. Then, you need to know the internals of `print` to determine which option is better (pre-computation through concatenation or let print do it)