# what is the difference between , and + in python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I just want to know the difference between , and + in python. example:
`a = 4`
`b = "string"`
`print(a, b)`or is it `print(a + b)`?

Comment: I recommend going through [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) as a start.

Comment: This is also related: [Is concatenating with “+” more efficient than separating with “,” when using print?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45215219/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

The first option you have `print(a,b)` will print i.e output the contents of what is stored within variable `a` and variable `b` respectively (in that order). The output would be: `4, 'string'`

Whereas the 2nd option, `print(a+b)`, you will try and add the contents but it won't be possible too as there is a type-casting difference between `a` and `b`. The error you would see is this: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str`.

And If you really want to concatenate those two variables, you can *type-cast* the variable `a` like this: `a = str(a)` and then go on with adding it to `b` like so: `print(a+b)` would output: `4string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(a, b)
```

will print a then b

```
print(a + b)
```

is doing `a + b` and then print it

in your case since the addition of an integer and a string is not defined it raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

Printing `(a, b)` will print the integer, then the string followed by it:

```
4 string
```

Printing`(a + b)` will raise an error, because the `+` sign concatenates two strings, but it is unable to convert the integer to type string.

EXPLANATION:

`(a, b)` treats the two items as separate elements in a tuple, whereas `(a + b)` tries to concatenate the two items.